# dell inspiron fails to update from 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, updates, 22.04, dell

i did `sudo do-release-upgrade` on my dell inspiron. It ran correctly, I didn't notice any errors. When restarting, it showed an error in dell-Linux-assistant and after uninstalling it stopped. However, when I run `lsb_release -a` or look at the machine information, the version shown is still 20.04

`lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (fossa-cory-tgl X60)
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

`cat /etc/*-release`:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (fossa-cory-tgl X60)"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

`apt policy base-files`:

```
base-files:
  Installed: 12ubuntu4.4
  Candidate: 12ubuntu4.4
  Version table:
 *** 12ubuntu4.4 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     12ubuntu4 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to manually reinstall lsb_release to solve the problem

```
apt-get remove lsb_release
apt-get install lsb_release
```